# Trapping errors using cmd.exe in SQL Server job

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I have a job that runs a batch file as step1.  I edited the batch file ( mybatch.bat ) as follows:

```
     call sub: >>mylog.txt 
     exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
    command1
    command2
```

As you can see I forgot to add the sub. The job step is
`cmd.exe mybatch.bat || echo %ERRORLEVEL%` .
The job runs as successful and the history is as follows:
`call :sub  1>>D:\Server_Directory\Logging\Cmd_Shell\SQL_APD_download.log   The system cannot find the batch label specified - sub    C:\Windows\system32>exit /b 1    0.  Process Exit Code 0.  The step succeeded.`
How do I get SQL to fail the job, and not report Exit Code 0  ?

Comment: It's not SQL [Server] that needs to change the Exit Code, it's the script. The exit code `0`, in applications, means that the application exited successfully.

Comment: `cmd` will not use `%ERRORLEVEL%` as the ultimate exit code. For that you'd need to use `exit` without `/b`. Note that the `|| echo %ERRORLEVEL%` does not execute because a batch file setting an error level is not interpreted as a command failing. You have to explicitly test with `IF ERRORLEVEL` if you wanted that. In this case we want to pass on the value no matter what, though, so `cmd.exe mybatch.bat && exit %errorlevel%` should do it (disclaimer: not tested).

Comment: For `&&`, read `&` since we want to do it unconditionally.

Comment: `call sub:` is wrong, it should read `call :sub`; and `cmd.exe mybatch.bat` should probably read `call mybatch.bat`…

Comment: `exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%` can and should be replaced by just `exit /B` because of the command `exit` does not modify the value of dynamic variable `ERRORLEVEL` on not explicitly specifying an exit code. For that reason `exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%` makes never sense and can just result in wrong behavior on this command line is within a command block starting with `(` and ending with `)` or on being a command line with multiple commands.

Comment: The command line `cmd.exe mybatch.bat || echo %ERRORLEVEL%` results first in replacing `%ERRORLEVEL%` by the current value of dynamic variable `ERRORLEVEL`. So the command line becomes `cmd.exe mybatch.bat || echo 0`. Then `cmd.exe` executes the batch file. If the batch file execution ends with an exit code not equal 0, the next command `echo 0` is executed which is exactly what you don't want at all. I recommend to open a Windows command prompt window and run `cmd /?` to get output the usage help of the Windows command processor and read it.

Comment: It would be a good idea to use `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /V:ON /D /S /C "mybatch.bat & echo !ERRORLEVEL!"` to get always the exit code of `cmd.exe` returned to the parent process output also as value to standard output stream. There could be used also `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /V:ON /D /S /C "mybatch.bat || echo !ERRORLEVEL!"` to output the exit code to standard output stream only if not being equal 0. There must be added to `mybatch.bat` below `@echo off` also the command line `setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion` to process the batch file with disabled delayed expansion.

Comment: Mofi has the right answer. Thanks. It has been YEARS ( 27 ) since I wrote any  batch files and then it was just one-offs.

Comment: Mofi has the right answer. Jeroen, yours didn;t work , I think because of what Mofi wrote. aschipfl- Exactly - "As you can see I forgot to add the sub.". I know I made a mistake, the question was how to trap the error when you make a mistake.